# Как получить в РНР результат рекурсивного запроса WITH RECURSIVE cte?

Tags: php, mysql

объясните пожалуйста с этим кодом

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
  SELECT category_id, name,
         CAST(category_id AS CHAR(200)) AS path,
         0 as depth
  FROM category WHERE name='PORTABLE ELECTRONICS' # sub-tree root
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.category_id,
         c.name,
         CONCAT(cte.path, ",", c.category_id),
         cte.depth+1
  FROM category c JOIN cte
  ON cte.category_id=c.parent
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY path;
```

чем его обернуть.
Я так понимаю, что это рекурсивный запрос. Тогда получается :

```
$sql = "WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ........";
```

Что делать дальше?

```
if($result = $conn->query($sql)){
foreach($result as $row){
              $id = $row['id'];
```

Так не работает, но и ошибок не выдает.

Comment: А что именно не работает? Выполни запрос напрямую в БД и посмотри какие поля возвращаются.

Comment: Если не выдает ни ошибок, ни данных, это значит что запрос не вернул ни одной строки. Оборачивать же обычно, бд всегда возвращает массив строк

Comment: if кстати тут лишний. надо писать без него, просто $result = $conn->query($sql);. Из-за этого может кстати и ошибок не выдавать